# What does "on input" and "on output" means in options like ICRNL and OCRNL?

Tags: terminal, tty

The documentation for `termios` says something like this:

> **ICRNL**
>
> Translate carriage return to newline on input (unless IGNCR is set).
>
> **OCRNL**
>
> Map CR to NL on output.

But what does "on input" and "on output" means exactly? This is what I think:

- "on input" means when the terminal sends something to the tty device.
- "on output" means when `bash` (or any other process) sends something
  to the tty device.

Am I correct?

Comment: "On output" means when the *kernel* sends something to the tty device. E.g. `onlcr` means translate a newline into CR-LF. So user space only has to worry about writing a newline. When the kernel eventually sends it to the tty, that's when the translation happens.

Answer (score 1):

You need to think of it in terms of a "dumb terminal" (such as a vt100) connected to a serial port on the computer, and looking at it from the perspective of the computer.

So "input" to the computer is when the terminal sends data to the computer; eg when you type on the keyboard.

Similarly "output" is when the computer sends things to terminal; eg when it prints something on the screen.

With a more modern setup (eg a Linux console) we still have the same concepts; "input" is stuff typed on the keyboard, "output" is stuff displayed on the screen.

This matches the standard conventions of "stdin" and "stdout".

Comment: Correction - the VT100 is not a dumb terminal. It is a smart terminal - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal#Dumb_terminals

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, as far as *termios* goes, since it's only concerned with the communication between the terminal (a device for displaying characters combined with a device for entering characters) and the host computer.

That **"on"** may appear awkward, but it's just a short way of saying "in the process of doing input" or "in the process of doing output".